# Fastest way to read huge csv file, process then write processed csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, bigdata, dask

I have a number of huge csv files (20GB ish) that I need to read, process then write the processed file back to a new csv.

The head of the csv file looks like this:
[image]

The object of the task is to read the csv file and to compare the time from each line to see if it's within start and end times contained within a dictionary. If it isn't then the line is skipped, if it is then it is written to the new file.

Sounds very easy but due to the size being efficient is crucial and I need some advice.

I've tried a number of methods including trying to read the whole file in pandas which was taking a long time or crashing due to memory issues. I also tried opening and reading the file line by line then processing it but this also seemed to take a long time. My now line of attack is using dask but before I carry on  I wanted to see if anyone can give me any hints as to improving speed on:

1. Reading
2. processing - this seems to take a long time as I'm using the apply function in dask to apply the processing function to every row. When I tried this it was taking something like 3 hours to process one file.
3. Writing - Seemed to take a long time to write a single csv file of say 20GB. I tried using dask to output each partition then combining the partitions into one file which did seem to improve speed a bit.

What would be the plan of attack each stage above to produce the fastest results bearing in mind I have 16GB Ram?

This is the code that I came up with after reading your responses. I incorporated a bit of code to display the percentage complete. It appears that the % complete seems to slow down a lot when the file progresses, as if there is a memory issue or another problem. For a 20GB it was taking over 4 hours to process, which seems a very long time. I looked at the system resources during processing and CPU was sitting at about 16% and memory about 10GB of 16GB. Can someone tell me if this is the sort of speed I can expect or is there something wrong with the code?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from symbol_specification import darwinex_quote_hours, darwinex_symbol_specs
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import io
import tailer

# Software Variables and Information
__author__ = 'TBC'
__copyright__ = 'TBC'
__credits__ = ['TBC']
__license__ = 'GPL'
__version__ = '1.0.4dev'
__maintainer__ = 'TBC'
__email__ = 'TBC'
__status__ = 'Production'
software_name = 'TBC'


def get_digits(str_val):
    return len(str_val.split('.')[-1])


def get_in_filepath(dir_name, filename):
    return dir_name + r"\\" + filename


def get_out_filepath(dir_name, filename):
    return dir_name + r"\\" + filename.split('.csv')[0] + '_OOH_removed.csv'


def get_input_variables():

    dir_name = r"X:"

    # dictionary containing darwinex symbol id and csv filename
    run_details = {'CADCHF': 'CADCHF_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'CADJPY': 'CADJPY_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'CHFJPY': 'CHFJPY_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'EURAUD': 'EURAUD_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'EURCAD': 'EURCAD_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'EURCHF': 'EURCHF_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'EURGBP': 'EURGBP_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'EURJPY': 'EURJPY_mt5_ticks.csv',
                   'EURNZD': 'EURNZD_mt5_ticks.csv'}

    # remove out of hours ticks?
    remove_out_of_hours_ticks = True

    # round OHLC values?
    round_ohlc_required = False

    # remove trailing zeros - ** Saves sapce in the output file
    remove_trailing_zeros = True

    # get quote hours as shown in MT5 symbol specification
    quote_hours = darwinex_quote_hours

    # specify the broker timezone in hours
    # ****************************IMPORTANT NOTE******************************
    # The Quote hours specified above relate to the broker time zone which maybe
    # different to the timezone tha the tickstory data was downloaded in.
    # Following my data download guidelines the tickstory data should be downloaded in
    # UTC+0):00 Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London timezone WITH DST. The Quote
    # hours specified in the MT5 specification are in the broker server time
    # which could be different. For example Darwinex is UTC +2.
    # Therefore the broker time offset is +2. The code will then subtract 2
    # hours to any of the quote times before using them.
    # ************************************************************************
    broker_time_offset = 2

    # create input dictionary
    input_vars = {
        'dir_name': dir_name,
        'run_details': run_details,
        'remove_out_of_hours_ticks': remove_out_of_hours_ticks,
        'remove_trailing_zeros': remove_trailing_zeros,
        'quote_hours': quote_hours,
        'quote_broker_time_offset': broker_time_offset,
        'round_ohlc_required': round_ohlc_required,
    }
    return input_vars


def round_ohlc(line, digits, input_vars):
    # assign vals
    date = line[0]
    time = line[1]
    bid = line[2]
    ask = line[3]
    last = line[4]
    vol = line[5]

    if digits != 0:
        bid = round(float(bid), digits)
        ask = round(float(ask), digits)
        last = round(float(last), digits)
    else:
        bid = int(round(float(bid), digits))
        ask = int(round(float(ask), digits))
        last = int(round(float(last), digits))

    # assemble line
    if input_vars['remove_trailing_zeros']:
        line = [date, time, f'{bid:.{digits}f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'),
                f'{ask:.{digits}f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'),
                f'{last:.{digits}f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.'), vol]
    else:
        line = [date, time, f'{bid:.{digits}f}', f'{ask:.{digits}f}',
                f'{last:.{digits}f}', vol]

    return line


def get_weekday_string(day_digit):
    weekdays = {0: 'Mon',
                1: 'Tues',
                2: 'Wed',
                3: 'Thurs',
                4: 'Fri',
                5: 'Sat',
                6: 'Sun'}

    return weekdays[day_digit]


def get_weekday_string(day_digit):
    weekdays = {0: 'Mon',
                1: 'Tues',
                2: 'Wed',
                3: 'Thurs',
                4: 'Fri',
                5: 'Sat',
                6: 'Sun'}

    return weekdays[day_digit]


def remove_out_of_hours_tick(tick_datetime, symbol_quote_hours, input_vars):
    # get quote offset
    quote_offset = input_vars['quote_broker_time_offset']

    # adjust tick_datetime for offset
    tick_datetime_adj = tick_datetime + timedelta(hours=quote_offset)

    # get quote hours
    day_string = get_weekday_string(tick_datetime_adj.weekday())
    quote_hours = symbol_quote_hours[day_string]

    # initialse keep tick to False (remove)
    remove_tick = True

    # iterate through all quote start/end pairs and check to see if tick is in hours
    for idx in range(len(quote_hours['start'])):
        tick_time = tick_datetime_adj

        # get date of tick
        tick_date = tick_time.date()

        # form quote hours start time
        start_time = datetime.strptime(quote_hours['start'][idx], '%H:%M').time()

        # combine the date and quote start time to form datetime
        start = datetime.combine(tick_date, start_time)

        if quote_hours['end'][idx] == '24:00':
            # special case. 24:00 means to the end of the day but it's not
            # recognised by python as a valid datetime. To get around this the
            # day is incremented by 1 and a time of 00:00 used which is equivalent.

            # form quote hours end time
            end_time = datetime.strptime('00:00', '%H:%M').time()

            # combine the date and quote end time to form datetime
            end = datetime.combine(tick_date + timedelta(days=1), end_time)
        else:
            # form quote hours end time
            end_time = datetime.strptime(quote_hours['end'][idx], '%H:%M').time()

            # combine the date and quote end time to form datetime
            end = datetime.combine(tick_date, end_time)

        # check to see if tick is within quote hours
        if start <= tick_time <= end:
            remove_tick = False

    return remove_tick


def write_conversion_log(input_filename, output_filename,
                         mod_string, conversion_time, input_vars):
    # conversion log file name
    working_dir = input_vars['dir_name']
    filename = working_dir + '//tickstory_tick_pre_processor_conversions.log'

    # determine if file exists or not and assign appropriate opening flag
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        append_write = 'a'  # append if already exists
    else:
        append_write = 'w'  # make a new file if not

    with open(filename, append_write) as outfile:
        outfile.write('--------------------------------------------------------'
                      '-------------------------\n')
        outfile.write('Conversion Details\n')
        outfile.write(f'Software Name: {software_name}\n')
        outfile.write(f'Software Version: {__version__}\n')
        outfile.write(f'Date/Time: {datetime.now(timezone.utc)}\n')
        outfile.write(f'Input file = {input_filename}\n')
        outfile.write(f'{mod_string}\n')
        outfile.write(f'Output file = {output_filename}\n')
        outfile.write(f'Conversion Duration: {conversion_time}')
        outfile.write('--------------------------------------------------------'
                      '-------------------------')


def get_start_end_date(filename):
    # Get the first 3 rows of the file
    df_start = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=filename,
                           encoding='utf8',
                           nrows=3)

    # Add column names
    df_start.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Bid_Price', 'Ask_Price', 'Last_Price', 'Volume']

    # create Datetime column
    df_start['Datetime'] = df_start['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df_start['Time'].astype(str)
    df_start['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_start['Datetime'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Get the last 3 rows of the file
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        last_lines = tailer.tail(file, 3)

    # clean up last line for line feed carriage returns etc by checking if line has a string
    while last_lines[-1] == '':
        last_lines = last_lines[:-1]

    df_end = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(last_lines[1:])), header=None)

    # Add column names
    df_end.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Bid_Price', 'Ask_Price', 'Last_Price', 'Volume']

    # create Datetime column
    df_end['Datetime'] = df_end['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df_end['Time'].astype(str)
    df_end['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_end['Datetime'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Add Start and End time to Symbol Info dictionary
    start_date = df_start['Datetime'][0]
    end_date = df_end['Datetime'][0]

    return start_date, end_date


def get_percentage_complete(start, end, tick_datetime):
    total_period = end - start
    period_complete = tick_datetime - start
    pct_complete = (period_complete / total_period) * 100

    return pct_complete


def main():
    # get input variables
    input_vars = get_input_variables()

    for darwinex_id, filename in input_vars['run_details'].items():

        # get filenames
        input_filename = get_in_filepath(input_vars['dir_name'], filename)
        output_filename = get_out_filepath(input_vars['dir_name'], filename)

        # get the start and end dates of the data so % copmlete can be determined
        start_date, end_date = get_start_end_date(input_filename)

        # get symbol quote hours
        symbol_quote_hours = darwinex_quote_hours[darwinex_id]

        # initialse list
        temp_list = []

        # read csv
        before_process = datetime.now()

        # initialise counters and mod string
        ticks_removed_count = 0
        mod_string = ''
        file_converted = False
        percentage_complete = 0

        # if processing requried open input and ouput files and process as requried
        if input_vars['remove_out_of_hours_ticks'] or input_vars['round_ohlc_required']:
            file_converted = True
            with open(input_filename, 'r', newline='') as f_in:
                with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as f_out:
                    # set up reader ad writer buffers
                    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
                    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
                    # for each line check whether datetime is within hours. If it is keep line, if not skip
                    for idx, line in enumerate(reader):
                        tick_datetime = datetime.strptime(line[0] + ' ' + line[1], '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
                        if not remove_out_of_hours_tick(tick_datetime, symbol_quote_hours, input_vars):
                            # keep line
                            # convert OHLC values if required
                            if input_vars['round_ohlc_required']:
                                digits_round = darwinex_symbol_specs[darwinex_id]['digits']
                                line = round_ohlc(line, digits_round, input_vars)
                            # write line to new file
                            writer.writerow(line)
                        else:
                            ticks_removed_count += 1
                        # determine and output the % complete after every 1000 lines
                        if idx % 1000 == 0:
                            percentage_complete_new = get_percentage_complete(start_date, end_date, tick_datetime)
                            if int(percentage_complete_new) - int(percentage_complete):
                                percentage_complete = int(percentage_complete_new)
                                print(f'{input_filename} % Complete: {percentage_complete:.0f}%', end='\r')

        # calculate conversion time
        after_process = datetime.now()
        conversion_time = after_process - before_process

        if mod_string != '':
            newline = '\n'
        else:
            newline = ''

        # update tick removal modification string
        if input_vars['remove_out_of_hours_ticks']:
            mod_string = mod_string + (f'{newline}***Tick Removal***\n'
                                       f'{ticks_removed_count} ticks have been removed')
        else:
            mod_string = mod_string + f'{newline}***Tick removal NOT requested***'

        if mod_string != '':
            newline = '\n'
        else:
            newline = ''

        # update rounding modification string
        if input_vars['round_ohlc_required']:
            mod_string = mod_string + (f'{newline}***OHLC values converted***\n'
                                       f'OHLC values rounded to {digits_round} digits')
            if input_vars['remove_trailing_zeros']:
                mod_string = mod_string + (f'\nOHLC values trailing zeros removed')
        else:
            mod_string = mod_string + (f'{newline}***OHLC value conversion NOT requested***')

        if mod_string != '':
            newline = '\n'
        else:
            newline = ''

        # update case when no conversion is specified
        if not input_vars['remove_out_of_hours_ticks'] and not input_vars['round_ohlc_required']:
            mod_string = f'No Conversion performed as not requested in input parameters'

        # write conversion details to log file
        if file_converted:
            write_conversion_log(input_filename, output_filename,
                                 mod_string, conversion_time, input_vars)

            # print conversion details to the terminal
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
            print(f'Software Name: {software_name}')
            print(f'Software Version: {__version__}')
            print(f'Date/Time: {datetime.now(timezone.utc)}')
            print('Conversion Details')
            print(f'input file = {input_filename}')
            print(mod_string)
            print(f'output file = {output_filename}')
            print(f'Conversion Duration: {conversion_time}')
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------')
        else:
            print(f'input file = {input_filename} - {mod_string}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Don't use Pandas or Dask for a streaming task like this, the built-in `csv` module will do absolutely fine for both reading and writing.

Comment: Also, please (a) post your (example) data as text (b) and post some code too...

Answer (score 3):

A basic pattern for filtering a CSV looks like:

```py
import csv

f_in = open("input.csv", newline="")
f_out = open("output.csv", "w", newline="")

reader = csv.reader(f_in)
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

writer.writerow(next(reader))  # transfer header, if you have one

for row in reader:
    if meets_my_condition(row):
        writer.writerow(row)

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

For simple *row filtering*, this is as fast and memory efficient as you can do it in Python: the reader is iterating a row at a time, so no more than one row in memory at a time; the file reads/writes are buffered, so the IO bottleneck is as low as your system and Python will allow.  Any other framework/lib—Dask, etc...—will probably impose some performance overhead compared to this; and [never use Pandas to iterate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/246801).

Based on my understanding of your screenshot and description, `meets_my_condition` needs to check if the value in column 2 is within a range of times; that could look like:

```py
def meets_my_condition(row: list[str]) -> bool:
    return row[1] >= "00:00:00" and row[1] <= "12:00:00"
```

Given this input CSV:

```
Col1,Col2
a,01:00
b,10:00
c,13:00
d,07:00
e,23:00
f,00:00
```

I get this output CSV:

```
Col1,Col2
a,01:00
b,10:00
d,07:00
f,00:00
```

I've spec'd operations like this before, and memory barely exceeds Python's minimum footprint of 7-8MB on my laptop, so with 16GB you'll have more than enough headroom.

Comment: Nice answer. The csv module is very useful!

Comment: Thanks very much, I will look into implementing something like this. I wasn't aware of the csv module.

Comment: @machTucker, did this end up working for you?

Comment: @ZachYoung I've edited my question to include the code I've implemented. It was taking over 4 hours to convert a 20GB file. Not sure if this is typical? Seems like a long time to me.

Comment: Hi @machTucker, that's a really big program :) I'm trying to find a way to help you focus on the issue of this post, how to read/write a 20GB file... I'm guessing you're trying to mix-in my solution with what you already had, and I don't think that's going to work for you. In principal, I suggest you try to step back and focus on the solution as I presented it. Practically, remove any reference to Pandas, I see you're reading the entire file with Pandas in `get_start_end_date(fname)`... that's going to be incredibly SLOW just from a processing perspective, and will break your RAM budget.

Comment: Here is some more practical advice: 1) take my ~20 lines and run it on one file and see how long it takes... ignore the bigger picture of _the entire problem_ you need to solve, and make sure you're answering the question, "what's the quickest I can and read and write a 20GB CSV?", then, start layering in all the other things 2) mock up some files of varying sizes, take a single a row and write a small helper program that copies that row N-number times so you can get smaller files to try on before potentially committing (potentially) hours to reading the 20GB file.

Comment: **I believe** if you're reading and writing the CSV correctly, as I've laid, it should only be a matter of minutes, assuming your hardware is newer than 2010.

Comment: @ZachYoung. Thanks, I will break the problem down tomorrow and report back, using your code as the basis so I can use it as a benchmark. Regarding the use of pandas I'm only using that to load the first 3 lines of the file so that I can get the start time. It get's past that operation fairly quickly I think. Anyway I'll report back tomorrow.

Comment: @machTucker, ah, I missed the nrows=3 param.

Comment: If I want to post a follow up to my tests, where do I post. I'd like to post the code I've used for the tests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252004/discussion-between-zach-young-and-machtucker).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for the specific details of your task, but it seems fairly simple to me. Since you haven't provided an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I will try with a **pseudocode-like:**

```
# Let input_filename be your 20gb .csv file
# Let output_filename be your filtered output file
with open(input_filename, 'r') as f_in, open(output_filename, 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        # Abstract: with extract_time() you get the time information with any way
        line_time = extract_time(line)

        # Abstract: with satisfies_constraint you check the aforementioned dictionary
        if satisfies_constraint(dct, line_time):
            f_out.write(line)
```

This way you read the input file line-by-line in `O(N)`, checking the dictionary in `O(1)` and you don't load the entire file in memory.

What is the issue with this simple way?

#### Update:

I updated my initial answer to be algorithmic-enough and not focusing on the exact way you will implement the individual aspects of whether you will `split` the line or read it with `csv`, etc. IMO the question concerns the basic procedure of completing the task.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm not sure that this kind of optimizations are the issue here. machTucker talked about trying to read *whole* file in pandas so I suppose the question is in a far more fundamental spectrum. However, I will edit my code to be even more pseudocode-like.

Comment: Your edited post is IMHO much better because it really focuses on the major point. Deserves a +1...

Comment: Manually splitting is only slightly more performant than using the csv module, and the csv module will be 100% correct... CSV files can look deceptively simple, but the standard is quite complex with lots of rules: the csv module gets that all right, and is so fast/performant to try and do otherwise is setting yourself up for trouble, at least down the road.

Comment: @ZachYoung as I already said I think that the question is not implementation-specific but more for the algorithmic nature of what is efficient to do and to do not (like trying to load a 20gb file in memory).

Comment: I almost exclusively answer Python-CSV questions here on SO and this kind of question gets asked a lot. Since I've yet to see any viable competitor to the csv module for performance and correctness, there's no "implementation agnostic" answer for me: the answer always starts with the csv module, then follows on from that. And I've also seen enough people trying to figure how to parse a CSV file with regex or some other way besides using the 100%-correct csv module, that anything other than showing the csv module is a non-starter for me.

Comment: I (think) I have tried implementing something like this and it was taking in the order of 3 hours. I will compare what you have to what I wrote. Many thanks for your thoughts.